# Setting minimum width of a RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to set a minimum width for the items of a RecyclerView with a GridManagerLayout

If I put 5 items per row it looks great but when I put 20 items per row the size of the item is like 20 dp but I want it to be at least 120 dp, How I can do that?

```
 GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(ActividadesColectivasPlazasActivity.this, columnas);


 adapter = new PlazasAdapter(ctx, listaPlazas);

 mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
 mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Layout

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <view
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:minWidth="500dp"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view" />
    </LinearLayout>





</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Adapter xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:minWidth="120dp"
android:background="@drawable/fondo_stroke_gris"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center" 
tools:context="com.psapp_provisport.activity.MenuActivity" >


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/nombre" />
```

Comment: You can use something like this, to automatically calculate the span based on the screen width: http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-autofit-grid.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To acomplish it I just change the miniumwidth of the Recycler View programatically with the number of columns*300

```
GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(ActividadesColectivasPlazasActivity.this, columnas);
mRecyclerView.setMinimumWidth(columnas*300);
```